# Derivative of multivariate normal density

Tags: calculus, matrix-calculus

I am not too familiar with matrix calculus, how can we go about taking the derivative of this quantity:
$$
\nabla_{x}Ax\operatorname{det}(2\pi\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, e^{ -\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu)'\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu)},
$$
where $A,\Sigma$ are $n\times n$ dimensional matrices and $\mu$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^n$; $n\geq 1$?

---

**What I've done so far.... the 1-dimensional Case**

I've computed the $(n=1)$ dimensional case to be
$$
\frac{e^{\frac{-(x - \mu)^2}{\Sigma^2}} (\frac{-(2 x^2)}{\Sigma^2} + \frac{(2 \mu x)}{\Sigma^2} + 1)}{
\sqrt{2\pi \Sigma}
}
.
$$

Comment: Are you trying to take the derivative or anti-derivative? Also, unless I'm missing something, I don't think you took the derivative correctly for the 1d case.
If you're trying to take the gradient of this function, the Matrix calculus page will be a good place to start.

Comment: The one dimensional case is good, also I'm taking the derivative...I took a look at the Matrix calculus but it got blocked up due to unfamiliarity...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define some new variables to reduce the visual clutter
$$\eqalign{
 M &= M^T=\Sigma^{-1}\,\,\,\,
 &w = (x-\mu) \cr
 \lambda &= \det(2\pi M)^{1/2}\,\,\,
 &\phi = \exp\Big(\frac{-w^TMw}{2}\Big) \cr
}$$
So the function of interest is the vector
$$\eqalign{f &= \lambda\phi Ax}$$
Find its differential and gradient, noting that $\{A,\lambda\}$ are constants wrt $x$.
$$\eqalign{
df
 &= \lambda\phi A\,dx + \lambda Ax\,d\phi \cr
 &= \lambda\phi A\,dx - \lambda Ax(\phi w^TM\,dw) \cr
 &= \lambda\phi\,(A-Axw^TM)\,dx \cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \lambda\phi\,(A-Axw^TM) \cr
}$$

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks greg! :)